# How to access a global variable in a closure? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, closures, scope

```
            var events = <?php echo $sf_data->getRaw('jsonData'); ?>;//some perfecly fine json
            var locations = new Array();
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            $(events).each(function(i,e){
                geocoder.geocode({address: e.place},function(results,statusCode){
                    locations[e.id] = results[0].geometry.location;
                })
            })
            alert(locations.length);
```

Okay, the question is easy.
How do i modify the **locations** array inside of closure?
The alert shows **0**.

Comment: You access it exactly the way you re. However, I don't see you define `events`, before you `each()` it. I think we need more code...

Comment: use firebug's `console.log` it's much better for debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The alert shows 0 because you modify `locations` asynchronously. Anonymous function where you modify `locations` will be called **later** then you show alert.

Comment: Is `geocoder.geocode()` async? If not, I see no async code in this posted example.  (I don't know anything about the Google Maps API)

Comment: aw, snap. I forgot it's async. I guess that solves the problem, thanks